# Working with huge textures with static part

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone, png, textures

I'm writing iPad cocos2d game with animations.

Designer gave me frames for each animating character in png. I'm using TexturePacker to pack my textures. But one of character is very big (600x600 pixels). And there 200 frames of animation. So, it will be very big memory part if I will pack it with TP to some atlases. But really not all 600x600 pixels are changing. Character has only moving hands and legs.

I think, I should cut static part from frames and cut dynamic parts from each frame to decrease memory usage. Is there some existing instrument for this? Or there is some better way to do in my situation?

Comment: Just FYI: 200 times 600x600 pixels with 32-bit color depth equals 275 MB of texture memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others with same problem:

After all I refused Cocos2d and write game with video. Huge animations was prerendered in video file, small animations I overlayed with imageView.animationImages.

You can change video playbackTime to add interactions.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no instruments for such task. And 200 frames 600x600 pixels.... I am sure that you will not be able to place all these frames to memory with other textures as backgrounds, other effects, etc.. It is too much for mobile device. Even for iPad. You should ask your artist to reduce frames number and size as possible.

For example, few months ago I got animation with 200x300 pixel frames. And actually content was only about 100x100 pixels. All other place in these frames was filled with glow. After glow was removed, it was not look such cool as before, but it was good too. And reduced memory problems.

Comment: Thx! I wrote python script and cut small rectangles with head, legs and arms from big frames. After that, all frames fits in 4 2048/2048 atlases.